# Create categories of individuals from data about them

Tags: categorical-data, pca, data-transformation

I have a big amount of individuals and few variables defining them (between 5 and 10). I'd like to be able to categorize the individuals in few categories, regarding the values of the variables.

I think the idea should go around principal component analysis, but that makes continuous axis, which is not quite what I'd like to do.

Which way should I approach this problem?

Example to illustrate better my problem:

I have an information about a lot of animals: their size, siblings at one time, body temperature, etc.
I would like to extract "types" of animals, which I guess would be something around "big mammals", "small mammals", "reptilians" etc.

Comment: Do you know the true categories? In this case you have a classification problem. If you don't know the categories and want to derive them from the data, there is an unsupervised learning clustering problem. Also please clarify do you know number of categories or not.

Comment: I don't know them. Thanks for clarifying the difference

Comment: You can start with an example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#example-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py ir if you prefer R http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to attempt something on multiple variables that will fail on a single variable.  Suppose you had only body mass.  Any categories that you create from mass will be artificial because mass is a continuous variable and it acts continuously when relating it to other variables.